# Including sourcecode for debugging from other project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

i got 2 independent Java Projects in Eclipse.
One is built to a Jar and is later on included as a library in the other (main) project.

So when i start the main project and attach a remote debugger on it, i need to put a breakpoint on one line of the included jars src.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the launch configuration, go to the Source tab, and add the source folder of the included project.

Comment: you mean launch configuration for the eclipse remote debugger?